# how to see admob invalid activity/traffic report in daily

Tags: admob

usually I see admob invalid traffic report only in the transaction history (on the first date of month).
Can some one show me, how do I get invalid traffic report in daily?

Comment: you cannot, it's listed at end of month.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid activity report avaliable only on transaction history, they review the account activity at end of each month

More info [here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3342054?hl=en).